# Kafka consumer poll forever

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to figure out why `consumer.poll` hangs forever in my tests.

In debug mode it seems like consumer fails to find group coordinator in endless while loop.

My test code:

```
final String BROKER_PORT = "9092";
final String HOST = "localhost";
final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = HOST + ":" + BROKER_PORT;
final String ZK_PORT = "2181";
final Integer ZK_PORT_INT = Integer.valueOf(ZK_PORT);
final String ZK_HOST = HOST + ":" + ZK_PORT;

    final String topic = "test-topic-10";

    //start zookeeper
    String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    zookeeper = new TestingServer(ZK_PORT_INT, new File(path));
    Thread.sleep(5_000);

    //start broker
    final File logDirectory = Files.createTempDir();
    logDirectory.deleteOnExit();
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper.getConnectString());
    p.put("broker.id", "1");
    p.put("num.partitions", "1");
    p.put("host.name", HOST);
    p.put("port", BROKER_PORT);
    p.put("log.dir", logDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    p.put("auto.create.topics.enable", "true");
    p.put("delete.topic.enable", "true");
    p.put("log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size", 2 * 1024 * 1024L + "");
    new KafkaServerStartable(new KafkaConfig(p)).startup();

    //send one record with producer
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "key", "val"));

    // Try to poll record with consumer
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
    System.out.println("POLL!");
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofDays(1));
    System.out.println(records);
```

Comment: With `Duration.ofDays(1)` you're telling the client to "wait for up to a day before getting messages"

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, that is an example code. In reality I'm using WakUpException

Comment: If you can post the code related to  KafkaServerStartable that is not working that'd be great

Comment: @VaibhavGupta it's already posted. With the code above `consumer.poll` operation hanging out forever, because consumer fails to find coordinator

Answer (score 2):

Add the following property to your consumer and try again

```
 properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

Comment: If the solution works do tell me i will explain it to you

Comment: thank you, your solution works! I suppose because consumer was launched after producer send, right? But it works only if I'm running zookeeper and kafka broker at docker. With `TestingServer` and `KafkaServerStartable` related code it still does not work

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.Your assumptions are correct default value for this property is latest and consumer was launched before.

Comment: I appreciate your help and upvoted your answer, but the question is not solved till I will be able to poll messages using `TestinServer` and `KafkaServerStartable`. I still have to launch Zookeeper and Kafka broker in docker

Comment: Ok,i will see if i can provide more help regarding that.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have kafka in a container and consumer.poll hangs forever, even if my consumer is config to auto reset at earliest. I'm calling it from a remote machine and my advertised listeners are configured as such : KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey, please read this essay about the [network in kafka](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)